# Jess in Protege: multi-slot setting issue

Tags: java, protege, jess

Based on the example rule `AssertingHasSiblingMulti1` for multi-slot setting given in [AddingRuleWithJessTab](https://wiki.csc.calpoly.edu/OntologyTutorial/wiki/AddingRuleWithJessTab) I have created the following Jess rule for setting multi-slot values on my property foundPollutionSources:

```
(defrule findPHPolluters
(declare (salience 553))
    (object 
        (is-a http..#PollutionSources)              
        (OBJECT ?sitepoll)          
        (http..potentialPollutant           
        $? ?b&:(eq (instance-name ?b)(instance-name http..#pH)) $?) 
        (http..#pollutionSourceName ?psName) 
        (http..#pollutionType ?psType) 
    )     
    (object 
        (is-a http..#MeasurementSite) 
        (OBJECT ?loc)
        (http..#hasSourcesOfPollution $?sitepoll_list)
    )
    (object 
            (is-a http..#ModeratePHMeasurement) 
            (OBJECT ?mob)
            (http..#observationResultLocation ?loc)
            (http..#foundPollutionSources $?existing_poll_list)
    )
=> 
    (if (not (member$ ?sitepoll $?sitepoll_list)) then 
    (printout t "pH pollution source: " ?psName " (Location: " ?psType ")" crlf)
    (slot-set ?mob http..#foundPollutionSources (create$ $?existing_poll_list ?sitepoll))
    )     
)
```

But, when I run this rule the following exception appears:

> Jess reported an error in routine ValueVector.set     while executing
>   rule LHS (MTELN)  while executing rule LHS (TECT).   Message: Bad
>   index 117 in call to set() on this vector:...

Answer (score 0):

There is a deviation from the usual Jess usage pattern of a variable bound to (part of) a multislot value. Observe:

```
(object 
   ...
  (http..#foundPollutionSources $?existing_poll_list))
```

The prefixed '$' causes all values in the foundPollutionSources slot to be bound to `?existing_poll_list`. The usual usage (cf. the Jess manual and the linked example) would be, for instance:

```
(printout t "pollution sources " ?existing_poll_list crlf))
```

But your RHS code has

```
 (create$ $?existing_poll_list ...)
```

Note the spurious '$' - I'd omit it and try again.

I don't know what protege and/or Jess might make of this, and I don't have the time to research it in the latter.

Comment: I don't want to printout the instancesas you say, but instead I would like to fill out the slot foundPollutionSources values with ?sitepoll instances. I tried to remove the '$' symbol, the error does not appear but yet again the goal is not achieved